# How to get first item of value in service response from array of objects in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have an empty numbers array and

```
public numbers :number[] =[];
```

The api response is here in service :

```
[
{"productID":1,"productName":"Phone","price":19.96},
{"productID":3,"productName":"Phones","price":18.96},
{"productID":2,"productName":"Laptop","price":2000.96
}]
```

Need to get First price value and pass to public numbers :number[] here How to do that.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild('mycanvas')canvas:ElementRef; 

public numbers :number[] =[]; 

 public products:IProduct[];
 constructor(private _productService:ProductService)
    {
    }

 ngOnInit():void{

    this._productService.getProducts().subscribe((response) => {
  console.log(this.numberss = response);


  for(let item of response)
    {     
    console.log("ff" +item.price);
    this.numbers.push(item.price); // need to get first value and assign to 
                                   array 

    }
    }),(err)=> {this.errorMsg =<any>err};

  public doughnutChartLabels:string[] = ['Mobiles', 'Laptops'];
  public doughnutChartData:number[] = this.numbers;
  public doughnutChartType:string = 'doughnut';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without for loop, you can simply assign as,

```
 this.numbers.push(response[0].price);
```